# Docker: Unable to access container from browser in host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker-compose.yaml to create containers

```
version: '2.4'

app:
    hostname: app
    build: .
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
      PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE: 1
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.10
    user: "root:root"

    command: /bin/bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.10.1
  outside:
    external: true
```

I successfully created a container but unable to access the app through a browser in a host machine.

I typed 192.168.10.10 in browser to access but it made timeout error

Comment: what is output when  hit  `http://localhost`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan the browser shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Comment: what's the output `docker ps` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan 
the output of docker ps  is  0799cac7ec9f        app   "/bin/bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"   29 minutes ago      Up 29 minutes                                app

Comment: you don't access using URL because the container didnot expose port, you just `tail logs` is a main process on container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker-compose file add this line:

```
app:
    hostname: app
    build: .
    ports:
    - "port:port01"
```

`Port` is port you would like to expose to outside. You can check on host by access URL `http://localhost:port`

`port01` is port which is configure in Dockerfile, its application port.